# In Objective-C, is [super message] actually better if it in the form of [self super#message]?

Tags: objective-c, oop

I looked into some language for a while, and look at Objective-C's

```
[super message];
```

In fact, isn't it more accurate if there is some form like:

```
[self super#message];
```

?  That's because we are still sending a message to the same object, which is `self`, but the message is a different one, which is the definition of `message` in the superclass.  So isn't it more accurate that we don't change the word `self`, but change the `message` part instead?

**Update:** this is a comparison between Javascript's way:

```
Author.superclass.call(this)
```

and `Author`'s superclass is `Person`.  So it is the same as `[this superclass's constructor]`, or is the same as `[self super#init]` (although `init` and constructor in Javascript are not exactly the same, but it is just to use as an example)

Comment: I believe the message is the same but it is sent to a different handler.

Comment: or maybe we can say, the final destination of the message -- the "method" invoked, is different

Comment: Then you just answered your own question. It is not a "different message".

Comment: No - it makes no sense. If you examine the runtime APIs, (e.g. `objc_msgSend` & `objc_msgSendSuper`), you would notice that the target of the two **is** different!

Comment: isn't the method invocation still on `self`?

Comment: Is this what you want instead: `[[self super] message];`

Comment: @動靜能量 No, the target is different. You invoke the method on a special struct which does runtime wizardry to determine which method imp to actually call.

Comment: if inside of drawRect, self is the memory chuck of 0x00fe0020 to 0x00fe0086, then when `[super drawRect: ...]`  is called, isn't the memory chuck of 0x00fe0020 to 0x00fe0086 still being used, but not other memory chuck?

Answer (score 2):

From a purely API standpoint (to which this refers) this makes no sense. If you look at the APIs relating to sending a message to `self` vs `super`, you would see the following:

**[objc_msgSend](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend)**:

```
id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)
```

In this case, `theReceiver` is `self`, and `theSelector` is `message` (after that is the args list, which we won't get into right now).

Compare this to 
**[objc_msgSendSuper](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSendSuper)**:

```
id objc_msgSendSuper(struct objc_super *super, SEL op,  ...)
```

Well wait a minute, that takes a totally different type as it's receiver! Looking into what `super` means gives us the following declaration:

```
struct objc_super
{
    id receiver;
    Class class;
};
```

An astute user would notice that this definition is invalid in ARC, but that's beyond the scope of this post.

What `struct objc_super`, then, allows us to do is to send a specific message to a specific class somewhere along the inheritance chain, which actually would allow us to skip huge parts of implementations if we wanted to.

So, with that said, the 'real' way you should do this would be the Java anonymous class (or C++) equivalent:

```
[MySuperclass.self message];
```

However, that is invalid because all types have the `self` message already declared, to point right back at themselves! So instead, we end up using the `super` keyword as a shortcut for

```
&(struct objc_super) { self, [[self class] superclass] }
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Super is almost the same as self, except that you're not calling methods defined in your own class, but your super class instead.  Adding hashtags to programming seems bad anyways...

Comment: we can use different notations... but what I try to get at is, it is still `self`... it is the message part that has changed

Comment: If `[super message]` and `[self super#message]` really was the same, which one would look cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be the same.

First, it would break the OOP paradigm, because you should not need to change the name of the method each time you subclass.

Next, suppose you have a class hierarchy like this:

- class A, method foo and superfoo declared
- class B, inherits class A, method foo declared
- class C, inherits class B, method foo declared

Then calling [instanceOfC superfoo] will call the method in A, not method foo in B.

If you meant "`super#`" to be only a construction logic, it won't help either, because the dynamic resolution logic of methods in Objective-C won't be really respected.

Anyway, it's just a matter of syntax. the Objective-C language syntax is defined this way, you could argue that they should have used `parentClass` instead of `super` or any `super#` construct or whatever, that's just the language definition and they had to do choices anyway ;)

Comment: what do you mean `foo` and `superfoo` both defined in class A?  Supposedly, the `super#foo` isn't related to `superfoo` at all

Comment: Ok so you meant only some construction logic and syntaxi sugar only. So that's only a question open to debate and choices. They could also have chosen any other syntax to fit that, there is no real answer to your question then, I don't really understand which kind answer you expect?! (But the way the Objective-C Runtime is implemented, the method resolution as more logical by calling the method on `super` than calling another pseudo-method, essentially because of the dynamic resolution mechanism anyway)